# SQL Server BAK file with protection is beaten by SA user?

Tags: sql-server, security

In my work I have a `BAK` file (which I'm working on in `SSMS`) and the system Admin gave me permissions via my `Active directory` .

NOw ,

If I'm taking the bak to another place (e.g. home), and I'm adding the sa user (which is me, and I don't have Server Environment in my house) as full controller.

Should I be able to have `full control over it` (at home )?

Comment: The `.bak` file in SQL Server is a **backup** - you cannot be "working on it" - all you can do is restore it to a SQL Server running on some machine. Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense...

Comment: I meant a SqlServer which after I'm making a BAK file of him

Comment: This question is more geared towards Database Administrators. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a backup file with no encryption, then you can restore it on your local machine as `sa`.  When you do this, though, the database users will be orphaned, and you will have to modify that.  No big deal, and as an `sa` you'll already be mapped to the `dbo` user, but if you have an application hitting the database using a different database login/user then that will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are administrator on your machine at home you should have full control.  The only items you may not be able to get to is if certain columns are encrypted.